# Arcpy not supporting in djnago in all machine but some machine it supporting

Tags: django, arcpy

I have a Django application running in a virtual Conda environment generated from ArcPro. I need to use the arcpy library in this Django application, which is why I used the virtual environment. However, the class I used with arcpy is working on some machines but not on others. I used the subprocess method, and it worked at that time since arcpy is running outside of Django with that method. Why is arcpy not compatible with Django?